# Unable to use package ctex using latexworkshop in Visual Studio Code on my mac

Tags: xetex, ctex, visual-studio-code

I am writing in Chinese so my understanding is pdflatex doesn't work for me. I have to use xelatex with the ctex package. This is my code, which worked perfectly in the TeXShop IDE that I got after installing texlive.

```
%课程大纲 
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{ctex} 
\begin{document} 
\title{课程大纲暑期新高三集训} 
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

But I tried to use Visual Studio Code to compile this since the autosave and auto rendering feature of Visual Studio Code is quite neat for me. But I am unable to compile it. When I clicked the below button, assuming it compile my code using xelatex, I got the following error message.[image]

```
[{
    "resource": "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/fontset/ctex-fontset-macnew.def",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Critical Package ctex: CTeX fontset `mac' is unavailable in current\n(ctex)\tmode.\n",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 65536
}]
```

I have searched online and apparently, I need to do something about changing the json file to use xelatex, but I only need to compile in xelatex once, so I didn't bother to change the json setting file, which to be honest is a bit confusing to me. so maybe the red-circled button doesn't compile my code using xelatex, as I imagined?

Comment: Show the log file about the error.

Comment: How is the recipe "Recipe: latexmk (xelatex)" defined?